# Match any PHP header() tag inside PHP for Headers

Tags: java, regex

What is the correct regular expression in Java to get the content of any PHP `header()` WITHIN `<? ?>` or `<?php ?>` tags and not commented? I have been pulling my hair out. I've been going over the regular expression manual, but whatever I try doesn't work.

http://regexr.com/3fi39

`(.*)header\s+\((\"|\').*?(\"|\')\)\;?(.*)`

This is where I have been testing my expression. I haven't even gotten to adding PHP tags because I can't get the base expression to work. I'm on day 3 of delaying this feature...

Another try (Thanks chris85) which works

`(.*)header\s*\(("|')(.*)("|')\)\;(.*)`

Comment: do you want all the text of a file? question is not clear...

Comment: Basically I am scanning a buffer for header tags, and I want to extract the header to re-purpose in Java sending the response. So I'm trying to use this with Matcher to extract the header to re-use.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to get a match... but more than I need. How would I just get the content of the header back?

Comment: That looks more like the complex regex I'm used to not understanding at all haha. Thanks a lot for the help Chris85. I'll mark this resolved whenever it lets me. If you want to add your breakdown you gave me as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first regex failed to match because the `+` quantifier requires a match, the `*` is zero or more occurrences. So `\s+` required at least 1 whitespace but `header(` has no whitespace. You can use the following regex to extract the contents of a PHP header call:

```
header\(('|")([^\1]+?)\1\)
```

The `('|")` is a single quote or double quote. The same as `(["'])`. The `[^` is a negated character, meaning all characters listed inside are not allowed. The `\1` is a back reference to the first character we matched (which was an encapsulating quote). The `+` keeps going until we run into a the expected closing quote and then a literal `)`.

Here's a regex101 demo as well incase some part of my description is unclear, https://regex101.com/r/D9rXDT/2/.

Comment: Thanks for much for your help. I do have one last little question. How would I negate `#` and `//` from before the expression to try and not capture commented out code?

Comment: Not sure if java supports it but a negative lookbehind would do it. `(?<!\/\/|#)header\(('|")([^\1]+?)\1\)`, also make the `+` non greedy with a `?`. https://regex101.com/r/D9rXDT/3/

Comment: Yeah it seems to have issues. It also has issues escaping the pattern `header\\((['|\"])([^\1]+)\1\\)` is how I had to escape it so it didn't complain about using escape characters wrong, but it doesn't match to any headers. I did use `header\\((['|\"])([^\\1]+)\\1\\)` which had no error in Eclipse but threw one during run time about `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 19
header\((['|"])([^\1]+)\1\)` which was the escape in `[^\1]`

Comment: Oh, you might need to double up all backslashes, one might be for java, and one for the regex.

Comment: That makes sense. With that in mind I tried `"header\\((['|\"])([^\\\1]+)\\\1\\)"` but it still was a no go. Very confused. No errors, so it is processing the regex. Just not matching like it does it testing.

Comment: I got ti functioning, I just don't understand why when it gets a match it breaks the script with no errors. No output is sent from the HttpServer. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: The regex101 is running pcre, I don't know what java uses that could be related..

Comment: Yeah i'm not exactly sure what was wrong with that one, because it even worked on a online Java Regex tester. I ended up using the alternate working method `(.*)header\\s*\\((\"|')(.*)(\"|')\\)\\;(.*)`